# Interpretation of error between Hessian approximation and real Hessian - Quasi-Newton Method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quasi-newton

$$ ||I- H_{k}^{BFGS}\nabla^{2}f(x_{k})||_{2}$$
, where $H_{k}$ is the inverse of hessian approximation at each iteration.

I am given this expression to assess the error in Hessian approximation in BFGS method. I know that if the approximation of Hessian converged to the actual Hessian, then the second term would be equal to Identity.

However how should I interpret this if the Hessian approximation is different from the actual Hessian? Why would we subtract from Identity and then take the norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I am not understanding the issue, or you're making it out to be more difficult than it really is.

You have a thing $A$ that should ideally be equal to $I$. The norm $\|I-A\|_2$ measures its distance from $I$; that's what norms do.